# plot data - boxplot in R how to remove NAs

Tags: r, plot, na

I have a data table of university data. We are looking at successes 1 against failures 0 where successes are completed.

There are about 5000 observations and 65 variables.

I have a heap of NAs in the success column. When I try to plot against the other data the NAs keep appearing as a category in my boxplot alongside the 1s and 0s.

The code I am currently using is:

```
plot(WAM ~ success,data=na.omit(students), main="Boxplot: success and WAM")
```

The data is in data.table. Any advice on how to plot the 1 and 0s only?

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example? For example just 10 rows with 2 columns - WAM, success

Comment: `students <- students[!is.na(students$success), ]`

Comment: If you want a boxplot, why not use `boxplot(WAM ~ success, data=students)`? It should automatically exclude `NA` cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(students) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = success, y = WAM))
```